# Reactjs style component differently when specific sibling component is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Say my App.js render consists of the routes defined below, `<TopBar>` is the site's navigation and it gets rendered on the page regardless of the route that gets rendered as it is defined above the routes, and what I want to accomplish is to style the `<TopBar>` component differently when `/:username` is rendered vs when the first 4 components are rendered.

```
App.js

render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div className={classnames('app_warapper', {user_app_wrapper:this.props.isAuthenticated, guest_app_wrapper: !this.props.isAuthenticated})}>
          <div className="App">
            <TopBar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />
              <Route exact path="/reset" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
              <Route exact path="/reset/:id" component={ResetPasswordPage} />
              <Route exact path="/create-username" component={isAuthenticated(UsernameCreation)} />
              <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={isAuthenticated(DashboardPage)} />
              <Route exact path="/edit-scope/:id" component={isAuthenticated(EditScope)} />
              <Route exact path="/profile" component={isAuthenticated(ProfilePage)} />
              <Route exact path="/logout" component={isAuthenticated(Logout)} />
              <Route exact path="/:username" component={PublicProfilePage} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```

Hacky solutions I came up with that I don't want to use:

- Render `<TopBar>` in every component individually and pass props to it to use different classNames when rendered inside `PublicProfilePage`
- Inside `PublicProfilePage` on component mounting store `<TopBar>`
  classNames, change them for duration of the component, on component
  getting dismounted set the classNames back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another simple alternative.

Wrap your `TopBar` component with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher-order component.

```
export default withRouter(TopBar);
```

It will inject `match`, `location`, `history` as props to your `TopBar` component and re-render the component when every time the route changes. So you can conditionally render the component based on these props as you want.

```
render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props

    return (
      //...your conditional JSX for TopBar
    )
}
```